# datepicker con array json desde php a js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-datepicker

Qué tal, recibo un JSON array desde un archivo PHP que contiene fechas, intento crear una variable de esas fechas con el fin de insertarlas en el campo **datesDisabled** (última línea) del calendario datepicker bootstrap. le hice *console.log* a fechas_tomadas, también *alert* y todo bien pero el calendario no lee la variable. gracias!

```
$(document).on('click','.doctores',function(){
    let horarios = $(this)[0];
    let idDoc = $(horarios).attr('idDoctor');
    $.post('/plane/vendors/modulos-agenda/reservas/step05.php', {idDoc}, function(calendario) {
        $(".bgcalendario").show();
        let response = JSON.parse(calendario);
        response.forEach(ver=>{
            var fechas_tomadas = ver.fecha.split(",");
        });
    }); 
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#calendario").datepicker({
        debug: true,
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        startDate: "+3d",
        maxViewMode: 0,
        todayBtn: "linked",
        language: "es",
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "1,3",
        // daysOfWeekHighlighted: "1",
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: false,
        datesDisabled: ['fechas_tomadas']
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás asignando un *array* con la cadena `'fechas_tomadas'` en lugar del valor que deseas. De cualquier forma, como el conjunto de fechas lo recibes después de haber cargado el `datepicker`, lo recomendable sería que dentro de la llamada de retorno del método `.post()` cargues el `datepicker` con la respuesta recibida.